# How to use java.util.Date to store a date of birth?

Tags: java

How do I set its value? I'm unsure which format it is in.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test(
    public Date dob;

    public Test(){
        dob = 10/01/1980 ??  "10/01/1980"

";
```

Comment: try `new java.util.Date(int year, int month, int day)`. Java is not a scripting language.. :D

Comment: that doesn't worth either sorry i forgot to mention i did try that

Comment: You're not sure whether it's MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: If you don't know the format of the text, then you are in trouble

Comment: no I'm not sure how to edit the value of dob.

Comment: for example I know `String a = "one"` so a = one, but now `a = "two"` now a = 2. How do I do the same kind of thing for `dob` E.g `Date dob = ???"`

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date`.  You should instead select the appropriate class in the `java.time` package.

Comment: besides your problems with aissgnment, variables etc; please user the newer classes from the `java.time` package; there you'll find 'LocalDate' which is a date without timezone and time which is more appropriate.

Comment: Instead of worrying about whether to use `Date` or `LocalDate` (although I'd suggest the latter too), the biggest problem here is you have no idea what you're doing. When you don't know how to assign a value to a variable, you should be reading tutorials and learning to program Java.

Answer (score 5):

I would encourage you to use LocalDate (JDK8) instead of Date,

```
LocalDate.of(year,month,day)
```

as Date is mutable and it's interface is hard to work with.

**Af for non JDK8 options:**

You can use calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,1980);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,10);

Date d = cal.getTime();
```

You can also use  SimpleDateFormat:

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("10/01/1980")
```

And lastly use Date constructor, but it's deprecated:

```
new Date( year,  month, date)
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation but I'm actually looking to answer my question please

Comment: @oneman This is a pretty good answer to your question. I don't know what your problem is, but you can't simply assign a "date" value because the Java language itself has no date type, it's just a framework class. Some other languages have native date types, so that might work there.

Comment: That actually does answer your question.  For example, you could use `Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("10/01/1980");`

Answer (score 1):

```
dob = new Date(1980,1,10);
```

And later to set a new value:

```
dob = new Date(1973, 3, 22);
```